# boto3 equivalent to gather all aws security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

With the old version of boto you could pull all security groups inside an aws account with something like:

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto3.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
groups = conn.get_all_security_groups()
```

However with boto3 the documentation isn't clear how to perform the same action. There's numerous references here dealing with changing policies with the new boto3 package, but not a mechanism to list all security groups and policies.

Is there a new method for this operation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boto3 provides a low level `client` which has almost identical method names that you can find in AWS API.
So to get ( or in aws context usually called describe ) you can do the following:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
client.describe_security_groups()
```

More info here: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_security_groups

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')

print([{"name": f_group['GroupName']}
           for f_group in client.describe_security_groups()['SecurityGroups']])
```

More Info:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_security_groups